# Erlang add value to a list in a variable

Tags: list, erlang, append

I have an empty list, and, in a special case, want to append a tuple to the list. How can I do that?

I tried several approaches:

```
case ReqFilePath of
    "style.css" ->
        ResponseHeaders = [{"Content-Type", "text/css"}];
    _Else ->
        ResponseHeaders = []
end,


case filelib:is_file(File) of
    true ->
        {ok, Content} = file:read_file(File),
        {output, Content, ResponseHeaders}; % Complains ResponseHeaders is not safe
    false ->
        not_found
end.
```

This does not work either, since the variable is already set. When I initialize ResponseHeaders = [] first, and then try to add a value to it

```
ResponseHeaders = lists:append(ResponseHeaders, [{"Content-Type", "text/css"}]);
```

I get a match error. How do you do this normally in Erlang?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way to do this in erlang is just to use another variable:

```
ResponseHeaders = [{"Content-Type", "text/css"}],
[...]
ResponseHeaders2 = ResponseHeaders ++ [{new_thing}]
```

Or you could make a function that builds the ResponseHeaders for you:

```
ResponseHeaders = build_headers(ReqFilePath).

build_headers("skin.css") -> [{"Content-Type", "text/css"}];
build_headers(_) -> [].
```

Don't forget to change your mindset to the erlang way! ;)

Comment: I'd definitely recommend the approach used here where you have a separate function to build the headers for you. Often the code becomes much clearer if you cut it into small pieces like that.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to use the fact that `case ... of` is an expression:

```
ResponseHeaders = case ReqFilePath of
    "style.css" ->
        [{"Content-Type", "text/css"}];
    _Else ->
        []
end,
case filelib:is_file(File) of
    true ->
        {ok, Content} = file:read_file(File),
        {output, Content, ResponseHeaders};
    false ->
        not_found
end.
```

And that should avoid any complaining. Note that I do not disagree with the suggestion to use a function, but I felt like I should explain that the 'unsafe' problem comes from the fact that you're using variables created within conditional branches of the `case ... of`.

Even though all the branches define the variable, the compiler still complains. By defining the variable outside of it, you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by extracting the case statement out of the function into a separate function:

```
get_response_headers(ReqFilePath) ->
    io:format("~p", [ReqFilePath]),
    case ReqFilePath of
        ["skin.css"] ->
            [{"Content-Type", "text/css"}];
        _Else ->
            []
    end.
```

And now I can get them by calling:

```
ResponseHeaders = get_response_headers(ReqFilePath)
```